# convert images and media url into blob url

Tags: images

Is it possible to convert `the_post_thumbnail` or `the_post_thumbnail_url()` into a blob url to use on the front-end of a wordpress website? I also need to add a vertical scroll with all the posts of a category, is there a good way to do it with bootstrap4 and css?

Comment: Yes, searching for "php image to blob" got me results like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845233/how-to-convert-jpg-image-to-proper-blob-data-type-using-php). What exactly are you having trouble with? Please only ask one question per question. (But to answer your second question: Sounds possible, but Bootstrap4 and pure CSS are considered "out of scope" for this site. Also, there's too little information in your question to properly guide you here as well.)

Comment: @kero I've found a solution for the menu, I will edit the question. I want to create a menù like the landor one. For the blob, I want to apply a filter hook on the wordpress function, I will take a look at the linked SO answer, but a mor wordpress friendly solution will be cool

Comment: There isn't a more WordPress-friendly solution - PHP will be needed. :) Have you checked out this answer? There are some helpful tips here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46305530/wordpress-getting-images-from-db-stored-as-blob-data

Comment: @WebElaine for wordpress friendly I mean using a filter befor the `the_post_thumbnail_url()` function is executed to output the data, Maybe convert the image to blob url can help?